# pass a custom data type list in a composite

Tags: gwt, liferay, composite

I created a composite, who has two method

- public void intItem(List dataList) //can take primitive data type
- public void vipInfoDataList(List dataList) // can take custom data type like: PlxVipInfo

[note: i define "PlxVipInfo" data type in composite sheared folder and import in composite class]
then i make the composite as jar and put in my protlet.
then call this two method:

```
List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);

CommonWidget mycomposite = new CommonWidget();
//mycomposite.intItem(myCoords);[**Note: when i call it gives data**]
mycomposite.vipInfoDataList(vips);[**Note: when i call it gives error**]
```

error is :

```
compile-java:
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/bglobal/liferay-sdk/portlets/customer-common-gridview-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/classes
[javac] /home/bglobal/liferay-sdk/portlets/customer-common-gridview-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/prolexic/portlet/proxy/client/PlxProxyServiceEntryPoint.java:174: vipInfoDataList(java.util.List<com.prolexic.composite.shared.PlxVipInfo>) in com.prolexic.composite.client.CommonWidget cannot be applied to (java.util.List<com.prolexic.portlet.proxy.shared.PlxVipInfo>)
[javac]                     mycomposite.vipInfoDataList(vips);
[javac]                                ^
[javac] Note: /home/bglobal/liferay-sdk/portlets/customer-common-gridview-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/prolexic/portlet/proxy/client/PlxProxyServiceEntryPoint.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 1 error
```

Now what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERROR clearly says, the custom type `PlxVipInfo passing through vipInfoDataList() method and the one declared are diffrent`.

They are 2 diffrent classes, one in the package `com.prolexic.composite.shared` and another in `com.prolexic.portlet.proxy.shared`.

So, in both places while passing as an argument and declaring the method use same type either 
com.prolexic.composite.shared.PlxVipInfo  or com.prolexic.portlet.proxy.shared.PlxVipInfo like below code snippet-

```
vipInfoDataList(java.util.List<com.prolexic.composite.shared.PlxVipInfo>);

public void vipInfoDataList(java.util.List<com.prolexic.composite.shared.PlxVipInfo>)
{
}
```

OR

```
vipInfoDataList(java.util.List<com.prolexic.portlet.proxy.shared.PlxVipInfo>);

public void vipInfoDataList(java.util.List<com.prolexic.portlet.proxy.shared.PlxVipInfo>)
{
}
```